# How to perform pre-processing steps before data being read by Airbyte S3 connector?

Tags: amazon-s3, airbyte

I am trying to use S3 connector from Airbyte to send data from AWS S3 (csv files) to my Postgres database. When setting up and testing the connector everything seems ok, but the problem comes when trying to add a destination. When I click on add destination I get this message in the UI:

```
Failed to fetch schema. Please try again
```

And in the logs I see this:

```
File "/airbyte/integration_code/source_s3/source_files_abstract/stream.py", line 260, in _get_master_schema
    this_schema = schemas[file_info]
```

I took a deeper look about how the csv files look like and I found 2 issues:

- " , " is the file delimiter and most of the lines in my csv file end with a comma
- At the end of the file I have other values that are not required so I would like to ignore them since they don't follow a table-like schema

Here is how the csv files look like:

```
col1,col2,col3
val1,val2,val3,
val1,val2,val3,
val1,val2,val3,
val1,val2,val3,

More:
someVal:, $ 1234.12 USD
otherval:, $ 1234.12 USD
lastVal:, $ 1234.12 USD
```

What I would like to do it's to "perform" some pre-processing steps on my file before Airbyte loads the data. In this case I need to ignore `n` number of lines starting from the bottom of the file, as well as delete all the commas at the end of each line. Is there any way to do that?

In addition, here is the file format configuration:
[image]

Thanks for your help!